# How to create a googlemaps marker from kml file information

Tags: google-maps, kml

To clearify:

I tracked myself via my google account...
exported the location history to an xml file.

Now I try to extract the coords from a particular time and location but the format confuses me (

```
<when>2010-05-28T16:02:44Z</when><gx:coord>0.265749 44.3140135 93</gx:coord>
```

)

if I insert the value on a googlemaps site that accepts lat and long I end up in Africa, but It is supposed to be France?

How can this information be used to get the correct lat/longtitude values?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that coordinate pair is supposed to be in France? I'm seeing it somewhere in Arizona north of Flagstaff. You may need to swap which value you use for lat/lon if you're feeding it into Google.

Comment: I used this site...http://netvicious.com/gps/...I edited my question with the real values from the kml file

Answer (score 1):

Lat/lng values need to be switched to 44.3140135, 0.265749

you should be able to copy paste this code to see your marker on a  Google map with your marker bubble with the info
TIME:2010-05-28 at 16:02:44
LOCATION:Lat 0.265749 Lng 44.3140135 Elevation 93m

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.3140135, 0.265749);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'TIME:2010-05-28 at 16:02:44
LOCATION:Lat 0.265749 Lng 44.3140135 Elevation 93m'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```